# Substitute text with number sequence using sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have this:

```
M6#pro [439640..444247 ][gbkey=CDS]
M6#pro [444328..445335 ][gbkey=CDS]
M6#pro [445407..445772 ][gbkey=CDS]
```

I would like to substitute the word **pro** with **numeric sequence** so the output will be:

```
M6#1 [439640..444247 ][gbkey=CDS]
M6#2 [444328..445335 ][gbkey=CDS]
M6#3 [445407..445772 ][gbkey=CDS]
```

Is it possible to do this using sed?? I tried this **sed 's/pro/NR/'** but it didnt resulting a numeric sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in case you are ok with `perl` then try following.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$A=1;} s/pro/$A++/ge'  Input_file
```

Comment: KGee you rejected [@oguszismail's awk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825878/1745001) saying you needed the solution to be in sed and then accepted a perl answer. Just sayin'....

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one.

```
awk '{sub(/pro/, NR)}1' file
```

replacing `pro` with `NR` (number of records processed --which is basically number of lines that got processed till that current line) with `gsub`

Comment: Use `sub()` not `gsub()` as you only want to do 1 replacement on each line.

Answer (score 0):

if data in 'd' file, tried on gnu awk:

```
awk -F'pro' '{print $1 NR $2}' d
```